# A strange phenomenon related to Tricomi's inequality for $J_0$

Tags: inequality, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

Context: I am preparing the next version of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) for 2018-2019 and I am including a new section about [Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), Voronoi summation and the Gauss circle problem, including some answers I gave on MSE and some material from Watson's *Treatise on the Theory of Bessel functions*. I was wondering about an alternative proof of Tricomi's inequality
$$ J_0(x) \approx \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi x}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(J_{1/2}(x)+J_{-1/2}(x)\right)\quad\text{for }x\gg 1 $$
and I realized that [*something strange is happening here and I don't know what it is*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC4r3QFnmQ8).

The Laplace transform of $J_0(x)$ is simply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$, and over $\mathbb{R}^+$ the function $a(s)=\frac{1}{1+s^2/2}$ provides a better approximation than $b(s)=\sqrt{\sqrt{1+s^2}-s}+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1+s^2}+s}{1+s^2}}-1$ for $(\mathcal{L} J_0)(s)$, but for large values of $x$ the Bessel function $J_0(x)$ is much closer to $(\mathcal{L}^{-1}b)(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(J_{1/2}(x)+J_{-1/2}(x)\right)$ than to $(\mathcal{L}^{-1}a)(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x\sqrt{2})$. **Why**?

Comment: And if you can include in you next notes something about sieve theory, I say easy explanations- examples.

Comment: @user243301: I will take that into consideration. In the meanwhile, I recommend the classical books of Greaves and Halberstam on such topic.

Comment: Page 70 of your notes: a commutative diagram stealthily (and accidentally, I assume) appears.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian: I almost got worried by that, but no, it is just a directed graph :D